# I would like to resolve VBA compiler error, expecting a function - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, compilation

I am getting a compiler error, expecting a function or variable.

The code is:

```
Sub Button8_Click()
' Test this
Caption = IIf(Button8_Click.Value, "On", "Off")
End Sub
```

The intent is to change the label on the button depending upon the value of the linked cell.

The above was built by selecting 'assign a macro' and I filled in the name of the button.  On research, it seemed that the first line should be:
Private Sub Button8_Click()
But I get a compiler error again.

The assignment line was yellow highlighted.

I took out the "_Click" with no gain.

I clicked reset, then run and a Macros window opened with no macros to select from.

With:

```
 Sub Button8_Click()
' Test this
Caption = IIf(Button8.Value, "On", "Off")
End Sub
```

The error is "Object required" and the assignment line was yellow highlighted.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what programming language

Comment: My guess is that the language is VBA. Can you please add the ```VBA``` tag and include it in the title. This way people sorting through these tag will notice your question

Comment: maybe vb.net?..

Comment: Thank you for helping.  I will be more informative in the future.

Comment: I suspect that Caption requires an object.  Please try  Button8.Caption = ....